# Jackson stream parser position

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

I am building a tool to parse huge JSON around 1GB. In that logic, I am creating `JsonParser` object keep reading till it reaches expected `JsonToken`. Now I create another `JsonParser`(called child), which should be starting from previous JsonParser token position without much overhead. Is there a way to do that in JasonParser API for that? I am using `skipChildren()`, which is also taking time in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call `releaseBuffered(...)` to get the data that are read but not consumed by the parser, and then prepend these data to the input stream (`getInputSource()`) to somehow parse the resulting stream (one way to do this might be to use an input stream that supports marks when constructing the parser).

However, since you're already using a stream based API, you probably won't get better performance than with `skipChildren()`.